# Looping through pixels in bitmap and add simple blur

Tags: java, android

I have a bitmap which I want to loop through every pixel and add a simple blur effect, I just want the to take the average of the current pixel and it's 4/8 neighbors. I've seen some examples but most are fairly advanced and I'm looking for something really easy.

What I have so far is:

```
int height = mPhoto.getHeight();
int width = mPhoto.getWidth();

int[] pixels = new int[height*width];
mPhoto.getPixels(pixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, height, width);
```

Comment: Have you simply tried downsizing then upsizing the image to obtain a blur effect? If not ill post some code.

Comment: I have, and it works kinda fine, but I want to try make some different image filters and the first step seems to be to learn/understand how to make a rly simple blur this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a method but i think it has a little of complexity. Don't worry I'll be here I'll try to make it clear for you =)

1: So first of all you have to create a BufferedImage Object

```
BufferedImage theImage = ImageIO.read(new File("pathOfTheImage.extension"));
```

2: Convert the BuferedImage into a int array. You should create a method to do that for you

```
public static int[] rasterize(BufferedImage img) {
        int[] pixels = new int[img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];
        PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(),
                img.getHeight(), pixels, 0, img.getWidth());
        try {
            grabber.grabPixels();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pixels;
    }
```

3: now you have an integer 1D array that contains all the pixels as a big concatenated integer, if you want to manipulate the colors separately, then you have to create 4 more methods : getRed(int) : int, getGreen(int) : int, getBlue(int) : int. those three methods give you the gradient of each color (0 ~ 255). One last method makeRGB(int,int,int) : int. This method create a pixels from the RGB colors component.
This is the core of every method ^^ :

```
public static int getRed(int RGB) {
    return (RGB  >> 16) & 0xff;
}

public static int getGreen(int RGB) {
    return (RGB  >> 8) & 0xff;
}

public static int getBlue(int RGB) {
    return RGB & 0xff;
}
public static int makeRGB(int red, int green, int blue) {
    return ((red << 16) & 0xff) + ((green << 8) & 0xff) + (blue & 0xff); 
}
```

4: last thing to talk about is how to turn the int array into a BufferedImage again. This is the code to make it ;)

```
public static BufferedImage arrayToBufferedImage(int[] array, int w, int h) {

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
    raster.setPixel(0, 0, array);

    return image;

}
```

I hope that helps you, Salam